# ADF: Self hosted integration runtime is unavailable after ADF redeployment

Tags: git, azure-data-factory

I am using ADF with GIT integration. I created self hosted integration and registered node using the keys. It was working fine for few days.

Then I deleted the ADF instance and created new instance and mapped it to the same GIT repo. Now the pipelines, data sets, linked services and integration runtimes are restored properly in the new instance of the ADF.

But the issue is with the self hosted integration runtime. I can see the self hosted integration runtime in the list but there is an error "Failed to get status" and it's unavailable. I verified that on the node that IR config manager is still running and it's showing that it is connected to self hosted runtime. But on ADF I am getting the above error.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create ADF
2. Link with Git repo
3. Create self hosted IR
4. Download and install IR on node
5. Verify that the integration is working fine
6. Delete the ADF instance
7. Create new instance and link it to same GIT repo
8. All the pipelines, data sets, linked services are restored
9. The self hosted IR shows " Failed to get status" error.

Questions:

1. Is this an excepted behavior, meaning whenever I will delete the ADF instance and create a new one, the original self hosted IR will be invalid and I will need to cerate new one?
2. If no, then what could be the issue?
3. If yes, then what's the advantage of saving this self-hosted IR in GIT repo? I am going to use Terraform pipeline and will destroying the re-creating the ADF instances on different environments. if self hosted IRs are going to be invalidated once I delete the ADF, is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

**Self-hosted IR can only be used to connect one machine to single Data Factory.**

But **we can create a shared self-hosted integration runtime in Azure Data Factory.** Then you can use the shared self-hosted integration runtime in another data factory.

Please follow the below steps to create a shared self-hosted IR:

1. In the self-hosted IR to be shared, select Grant permission to another Data factory and in the "Integration runtime setup" page, select the Data factory in which you want to create the linked IR.

[image]

2. Note and copy the above "Resource ID" of the self-hosted IR to be shared.
3. In the data factory to which the permissions were granted, create a new self-hosted IR (linked) and enter the resource ID. Follow below steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]